# How to restore Firefox profil

Tags: firefox

I recently build a new PC, which mean make an install on a new SSD. But I kept the old HDD, and I plugged it.

I want to restore all my firefox "data", to make it like if nothing changed.

I found the profile in `snap/firefox/common/.mozilla/firefox/i0f7arvw.default`. If I simply copy past the whole directory I've got an error stating that I am running an older version of Firefox and I should create a new profile.

So I try to copy only the needed files and directories. I achieved to restore the cookies and the caches. It remains the bookmarks (I stupidly forgot to do an export) and the history.

I saw [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/724047/how-to-restore-firefox-esr-data), but if I just copy the folder and run `firefox --ProfilManager`, I still have the same problem.

Comment: you can use `firefox` instead of `firefox-esr` if you have the non-esr version of fierfox

Comment: Indeed... I updated my post

Comment: what version of firefox are you currently running? What version of firefox were you running on the old PC?

Comment: I asked the exact same question to myself when going to sleep yesterday. And after wondering how to update Firefox (thanks to snap) it works well by simply copying the profile folder